# How do I set a window's position/size in a multi-monitor, mixed-DPI environment?

Tags: c#, c++, windows

I have a C# application that is attempting to create a customizable version of [Windows's Snap](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027324/windows-snap-your-windows) functionality through the native Win32 API. Via [hotkeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309(v=vs.85).aspx) my app modifies the position/size of OTHER application windows. My primary monitor is a standard 1920x1080 display. My secondary monitor is a 3200x1800 monitor set to 250% scale and placed to the LEFT of my primary monitor.

If I call [SetWindowPlacement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633544(v=vs.85).aspx) with a [RECT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162897(v=vs.85).aspx) at position (0,0) my window doesn't actually place the window flush in the corner. There's some padding. This is due to [GetWindowRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519(v=vs.85).aspx) vs [GetClientRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633503(v=vs.85).aspx). I can calculate this difference and adjust to account for the padding. This produces the counter-intuitive position of approx (-7,0). On a single monitor this result is pixel perfect.

However, if I attempt to place my window at (-7,0) in my mixed-dpi, multi-monitor environment it causes the window to appear in the correct upper-left position but... a width and height incorrectly scaled by 250%. This is true even if I place it at (-1,0). Amusingly, the super sized window at (-1,0) still has visual padding between it and the edge of the 1920x1080 screen!

I'm not completely surprised by this result. (-1,0) is on the other monitor after all. However, I can not find a way to place my window flush in the upper-left corner of a 1080p monitor that is adjacent to a 250% scale monitor. Neither SetWindowPlacement nor [SetWindowPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx) seem to offer a working path.

Comment: First question, have you marked your app as DPI aware?

Comment: Great question. My app is not moving its window. It responds to a [Windows HotKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309(v=vs.85).aspx) and calls SetWindowsPlacement on the focused Window.

I've been using Notepad as my test subject. I just observed that some apps, such as SublimeText, work correctly. While others, such as Notepad, do not. It might actually be that proper DPI aware apps are broken while DPI unaware apps are not!

Either way my code should be capable of correctly placing a window no matter it's awareness. But this gives me a new angle to explore.

Comment: You need at least `dpiAware>True/PM</dpiAware>` in the manifest, PM marks it to be per-monitor aware.  The "padding" is usually the border of the window, Win10 chrome does not use a true border anymore.  Some apps are borderless and fake their own chrome.

Comment: HansPassant, I added that, but it makes no difference. I clarified my question to make more clear that I'm changing the pos/size of other application windows. I can't control what their compiled dpiAware settings are. I may or may not be able to control runtime behavior.

[GetProcessDpiAwareness](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn302113(v=vs.85).aspx) allows getting the dpi awareness of a different process. For reasons unknown [SetProcessDpiAwareness](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn302122(v=vs.85).aspx)  only works on the current process.